# Azure Databricks API

Tags: azure, api, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-rest-api

Trying to use the Databricks API to work with resources programmatically.  I am using this microsoft documentto authenticate with a service principal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token

But I'm getting the following error

"Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS500011: The resource principal named
https://management.core.azure.com was not found in the tenant"

This is my full script.  What am I missing?

```
$ApiCommand = "clusters/get"

$DataBrick = "https://adb-3522222096750220.0.azuredatabricks.net"

$DataBricksResourceID = ""

$VaultName = ""
$KeyName = ""

$apiEndpointUri = "https://management.core.azure.com"  
$tenantId = ""  
$applicationId = ""  
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $KeyName -AsPlainText

$RequestAccessTokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"
$body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$applicationId&client_secret=$secret&resource=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d" 
$Managementbody = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$applicationId&client_secret=$secret&resource=$apiEndpointUri"  
$contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 

$AccessToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestAccessTokenUri -Body $body -ContentType $contentType  
Write-Output $AccessToken
$ManagementToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestAccessTokenUri -Body $Managementbody -ContentType $contentType
Write-Output $ManagementToken

$apiuri = $DataBrick +"/api/2.0/$ApiCommand"
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + $AccessToken.access_token)
$headers.Add("X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token", $ManagementToken.access_token)
$headers.Add("X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id", $DataBricksResourceID)

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiuri -Headers $headers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing `/` character in the management endpoint URI is really important - you need to specify it as in the documentation: `https://management.core.windows.net/`

You can also add this SP into the workspace itself, then you will need to get only one AAD token (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#--api-access-for-service-principals-that-are-azure-databricks-workspace-users-and-admins)).

Comment: Yep that was the issue. Thanks.  And yeah, we could add it to the workspace, but we're wanting the ability to transfer between databricks as we get new ones stood up and old ones decommissioned.